# .Net/C# Create synchronous websocket client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-core, websocket

I need to consume an api via websocket in a synchronous way, but seems like we have nothing like that available in .Net/C#. I found the following to consume [websockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netcore-3.0)/[signalr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) websocket services but any of them offers synchronous calls.

The reason why I need this synchronous is because I'm working in a multi-thread application, and it now consumes rest services which will be no long available because they were replace by websockets services, I cannot change the entire chain methods to async, because this service is not the only one being consume. Which means I already have a interface for many services in a rest way, I just need this one implementation being in a websocket way.

It is not a "Web project" btw, but a background service.